# Windows7 Hangs for 5 minutes loading OpenGL app

Tags: windows-7, opengl

I haven't been able to find much information about this : whenever a fullscreen openGL application loads on this new Win7 machine it black-screens for about 5 mins, then recovers like nothing happened. It does the same thing when switching back out of fullscreen.

DirectX based stuff works just fine. No other oddities on the system. Hardware is all completely new, applied latest drivers for graphics (GTX 570) and windows, still no improvement.

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: What applications did you use to test? Are you sure this is linked to OGL itself rather than the application that uses it?

Comment: Games have been the main test bed since I could usually verify very quickly which uses directx and which uses openGL. Exhibits on Star Ruler, Dwarf Fortress, Xenonauts, ToME. Nothing directx yet has had the same problem, I can try and get some fullscreen basic openGL application to test it for the sake of a more independent test case.

Comment: You could record system events with [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) and see if the 5 minute gap is in the events of the game as well. The results could point at the cause of this issue.

Comment: I have the log but it's kind of massive, what am I looking for? Err. nevermind. Just spotted it. It looks like yes the game exe itself goes silent for about 5 mins, nothing in events for it.

Comment: You're going to want to see what the last thing is the game does before it hangs (and possibly, what it does afterwards). The recorded events don't have to necessarily have caused the delay, but it's worth looking at.

Comment: It looks like the last thing before it hangs is just file IO on some game specific dll's. The first thing after it hangs though is access to the wow64 dll's... Maybe a 64 bit machine using the 32-bit mode has something to do with this?